# I cannot install Geocoder

Tags: 9

I have tried to install Geocoder v4.11 with `composer require 'drupal/geocoder:^4.11' --with-all-dependencies`, but instead I get incompatibility issues with Guzzle.

```
Problem 1
    - php-http/guzzle7-adapter 1.0.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^7.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.0.0, ..., 7.8.0] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - drupal/geocoder 4.11.0 requires php-http/guzzle7-adapter ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/guzzle7-adapter[1.0.0].
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/geocoder ^4.11 -> satisfiable by drupal/geocoder[4.11.0].
```

Comment: It looks like you edited composer.json to set geocoder to 4.11. Did you?